# What is wrong in my htaccess regular expression?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert this beauty of URL

```
http://insenti.ru/425/sayt-dlya-odinokih-ne-vybirayut/&page=2
```

into this

```
http://insenti.ru/texts.php?nead_id=425&page=2
```

So I use this regular expression in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule insenti\.ru\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)\/(.*) insenti.ru/texts.php?nead_id=$1$3
```

But it has a mistake and the redirect does not work.

Here is my entire htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://insenti.ru/search/err=nopage
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (album|chat|help|index|landing|process_data|search|signup|sympathy|user|userspecs)/(.*) $1.php?$2
RewriteRule insenti\.ru\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)\/(.*) insenti.ru/texts.php?nead_id=$1$3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^insenti.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://insenti\.ru/$1 [R,L]
```

When I check it using php preg_replace it works perfect:

```
$link = preg_replace('/insenti\.ru\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)\/(.*)/i', 'insenti.ru/texts.php?nead_id=$1$3', $link);
```

I will appreciate so much any help with that!!

Comment: So how is this URL: `http://insenti.ru/425/sayt-dlya-odinokih-ne-vybirayut/&page=2` containing `&` but no `?` ?

Comment: This nice url may contain anything. The important thing is how it is converted. I have a problem with converting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule` doesn't match domain name. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/[^/]+/(.*)$ texts.php?nead_id=$1$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: ^(\d+)\/(.*)\/(.*)$ texts.php?nead_id=$1$3

Comment: In rewrite rules there is no need to escape the forward slash